# How do I resolve an AutoComplete error when using CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to use the AutoComplete of CodeMirror, but I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'javascript' of undefined

```
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
    CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.javascript); // Error Here
}

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use autocomplete capabilities, you must insure to include the appropriate scripts, i.e. *show-hint.js*, *show-hint.css* and *javascript-hint.js* (which seems like the one causing the fuss here).

Take a look at the [autocomplete demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html)'s source code for a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i have included the scipts extracted from the codemirror package available on the site u have mentioned..

Comment: It's done..There were some objects which were not defined in files..I have to write them..we have to press ctrl-space here to activation , Instead if i want to show suggestions just by keystrokes , what should be change in code..?